# How to populate a collection in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to PostgreSQL and I am working on migration task. I am looking for an alternative of "bulk collect into" syntax in PostgreSQL or how I can achieve this functionality in PostgreSQL.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION test."printEmpIds"()
RETURNS test.emp_add
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
declare 
empIds test.emp_add;
begin
select ids bulk collect empIds from test.emp;
-- for idx in 1..empIds.count loop
-- raise notice '%%%', empIds.idx;
-- end loop;
return empIds;
end;
$BODY$;
ALTER FUNCTION test."printEmpIds"()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Basically I want to populate all ids from emp table into user defined collection empIds and return

Any help would be appreciable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you may return an array of integers `INT[]` by doing an `ARRAY_AGG` from  select

**Test data**

```
create table emp ( ids INTEGER );
insert into emp(ids) values(1),(2),(3);
```

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION printempids ()
RETURNS INT[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql
COST 100 volatile as $body$ 
declare empids int[];
BEGIN
     SELECT array_agg(ids) INTO empids
      FROM emp;
     RETURN empids;
END;
$body$;
```

**Result**

```
knayak=# select printempids ();
 printempids
-------------
 {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

To get them as rows, you may do

```
select * FROM  UNNEST(printempids ()) as id;
```

Although this feature can replicate Oracle's `TABLE` functionality using a collection, I would suggest you to use `RETURNS TABLE` and `RETURN QUERY SELECT ..` instead in Postgres.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION printempids ()
RETURNS TABLE ( p_ids INT )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
COST 100 volatile as $body$ 
declare empids int[];
BEGIN
     RETURN QUERY SELECT ids 
      FROM emp;
END;
$body$;
```

**Result**

```
knayak=# select printempids ();
 printempids
-------------
           1
           2
           3
(3 rows)
```

Or a simple SQL function also works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION printempids ()
RETURNS TABLE ( ids INT ) as 
$body$ 
  SELECT ids FROM emp;
$body$ LANGUAGE SQL
COST 100 volatile;
```