# How to get temp/virtual table in PostgreSQL from array of ids

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Oracle Query:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION case_filter(p_account_id IN DOUBLE PRECISION
                  ,  p_case_type_id   IN DOUBLE PRECISION
                  ,  p_activity       IN VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT NULL
                  ,  p_step           IN VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT NULL
                  ,  p_char_fld_obj   IN ct_char_obj DEFAULT NULL
                  ,  p_num_fld_obj    IN ct_num_obj DEFAULT NULL
                  ,  p_from_date_fld_obj   IN ct_date_obj DEFAULT NULL
                  ,  p_to_date_fld_obj   IN ct_date_obj DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS number_tab_t
 AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  l_case_ids number_tab_t;
  l_case_ids_local number_tab_t;
 BEGIN
    select array_agg(ccase.case_id) INTO l_case_ids
          from ct_case ccase
              INNER JOIN ct_case_type casetype
                 on (casetype.case_type_id = ccase.case_type_id and casetype.account_id = p_account_id)
                  WHERE  ccase.case_type_id = coalesce(p_case_type_id, ccase.case_type_id);
  l_case_ids_local := l_case_ids;
  IF p_employee IS NULL THEN
    RETURN SET(l_case_ids);
  ELSE
     SELECT DISTINCT array_agg(case_id) INTO l_case_ids
     FROM (SELECT case_id
           FROM    employee_data ed
                INNER JOIN  ct_case c
                    ON (c.employee_id = ed.employee_id AND ed.account_id = p_account_id)
                INNER JOIN l_case_ids_local () bc
                    ON (c.case_id = bc.column_value)
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(ed.last_name || ',' || ed.first_name || ed.middle_name), '[^A-Z,]', '') LIKE '%'|| replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(upper(p_employee), '[^A-Z,]',''),',','%,')|| '%') as re;
  END IF;
  RETURN SET(l_case_ids);
 END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Since we are migrating this query to PostgreSQL, we faced problem with table function. table(collection of integer) is not directly supported in PostgreSQL Is there any alternative in PostgreSQL?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what `l_case_ids_local` is? What does it look like? How was it made? What is your desired output?

Comment: @Adam Dadvar It's a collection of ids i.e array of integer

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `TABLE` operator and use `l_case_ids_local()`

```
INNER JOIN  l_case_ids_local() bc
            ON (c.case_id = bc.col) -- use the column name as 
                                    -- defined in the function.
```

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested. The function was compiled successfully but while calling this function I encountered  with the error.


ERROR:  function l_case_ids_local() does not exist
LINE 5:                     INNER JOIN l_case_ids_local () bc

Comment: @DilipChauhan : It's not possible to tell without seeing your function. Are you passing the correct parameters and referring with correct schema name ? or have you used double quotes with mixed case for the name while creating the function?

Comment: ERROR:  function l_case_ids_local() does not exist
LINE 5: INNER JOIN l_case_ids_local () bc                                     ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT case_id) FROM (SELECT case_id
FROM    employee_data ed
 INNER JOIN  ct_case c
ON (c.employee_id = ed.employee_id AND ed.account_id = p_account_id)
                    INNER JOIN l_case_ids_local () bc
                        ON (c.case_id = bc.column_value)

Comment: @DilipChauhan : In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864781/how-to-populate-a-collection-in-postgresql), you were quoting your function name `"printEmpIds"()`. Are you doing the same with this function? Either remove the quotes while creating or quote it here in your query where you call it.

Comment: I have another question: RETURN SET(l_case_ids)
This is a Oracle syntax but in PostgreSQL SET function is not compitable.
How can I get the same functionality in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @DilipChauhan : can't say anything without seeing your function. Edit your question and add the ddl of the function

Comment: @DilipChauhan : The problem with your functions is that you are trying to replicate the function "as it is" from Oracle by mimicking the exact functionality available in Oracle to that of Postgres.For eg: using definitions like `l_case_ids number_tab_t;` That's not a great  idea. I saw in one of your other questions @horse suggested you with better options like using an SQL function instead of plpgsql.The code would have been far simpler if you wrote it utilising the best option available in Postgres only copying the underlying functionality rather than making it look like the code in Oracle.